# Calculating products of permutations

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

This is a very simple question, but if I want to compute say $(12)(13)$, I see this as $(12)(13)[1,2,3] = (12)[3,1,2]$ which flips the elements 1 and 3. Now to calculate $(12)[3,1,2]$, do we flip the *elements* 1 and 2, or the elements in *positions* 1 and 2 (these would give us [3,2,1] and [1,2,3] respectively)?

Comment: While left multiplying by a transposition in $S_n$, usually you flip the numbers themselves, not the numbers in those positions. For example, here, you would switch $2$ and $1$ where they occur in the one-line notation, to get $[3,2,1]$. On the other hand, multiplying on the right hand side by a transposition would mean switching the elements in those places. For example, $[3,1,2](12) = [1,3,2]$. (Note : do not confuse one line and cycle notation. For example, $[3,1,2] = (132)$, which may be a catch point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A permutation is a function from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to itself.
Multiplication of permutations is function composition:
since we write functions on the left, we usually define
$$(\sigma\tau)(k)=\sigma(\tau(k)).$$
For $\sigma=(1\,2)$ and $\tau=(1\,3)$ then
$$\sigma\tau(1)=\sigma(3)=3,$$
$$\sigma\tau(2)=\sigma(2)=1$$
and
$$\sigma\tau(3)=\sigma(1)=2.$$
Therefore $(1\,2)(1\,3)=(1\,3\,2)$.

Comment: I believe you are missing a 1 in the last line.